# Assigning value to float data type crashes program

Tags: c++

I'm losing my mind here. Please someone help me understand what is going on.

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <conio.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
  float test;
  printf("You see me\n");
  test = 3;
  printf("Wont get here\n");

  return(0);
}
```

You see me is printed out then the app crashes before the Wont get here is printed.

Important to note that this compiles and runs fine on my system, but when this exe is transferred to a 32 bit, Windows XP machine it crashes.

Ints, Bools, char data formats work fine, but when I try to use floats/doubles the app just crashes with no error.

Am I not compiling this correctly in Visual Studio Express 2013 in some way that anyone can think of? Should I check myself into the local loony ward?

Comment: is this compiled as a 32-bit app?

Comment: It works for me in red hat using g++, and also here -- https://ideone.com/pOoO3u   Note that I commented `windows.h` and `conio.h` since I'm on Unix platform

Comment: what happens if you assign 3.0?

Comment: Use CodeBlocks instead of Visual Studios :P

Comment: What about `test = 3.0f`?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with different versions of the same DLL(s) on each platform.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Its compiled with the Platform Toolset = Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp). What else would I need to do to define it as such?

Comment: @dev_feed Crashes with 3.0 as well

Comment: @TimCastelijns Crashes with 3.0f too

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with your code but the project settings..please try this code by opening a brand-new default project and test again..look for your include directories and library paths..check assemblies etc. it is somehow using some runtime dlls that are not compatible etc.

Comment: @SemihOzmen This is really interesting. Okay created a new Win32 Console project with this same code. Except in this I only have included `stdafx.h` and `windows.h`. Same thing is happening. Do you still think Visual Studio Settings? The only setting I changed was `Platform Toolset = Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)`

Comment: If you are moving it to another machine, you (could be) getting a "side-by-side" (or similar) error. This is caused by a mismatch of the C++ runtime libraries you have on one computer and not the other (aka DLL HELL) You should be able to see the error in the event logs (control panel, type n event logs, its somewhere in there). To fix this, you have to install the newest version of the C++ run-time libraries on that machine (maybe, this is a giant pain of a problem).

Comment: Just to follow up, this is (one of the many) reasons why steam installs a new version of the C++ runtime for every new software install. It just doesn't feel like keeping track, just packages the one the software was built with with it and move on.

Comment: I do not have an inside info about v120_XP toolset..I do not know why you are insist on using this toolset but it may require such runtime dlls (for example a special build of msvcrt120.dll or something) that are not compatible with the ones in your system..so please read this toolset's details and requirements and check Runtime Libraries settings carefully. also test your code with release/debug configs.

Comment: @SemihOzmen Okay. I need to use that toolset in order for it to at least run on the other machine. If I don't set this, I get an error showing that the program isn't compatible with win32

Comment: Exactly what do you see when it crashes?

Comment: @AlanStokes  http://imgur.com/36JoZ69

Comment: This XP machine is a very lightweight machine and doesn't have anything installed on it other than the barebones XP. Would it be possible that I just need to install: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Supposedly it contains the "run-time components required to run C++ applications built in VS 2013". I'm going to give that a shot now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay found the issue with the help of a colleague.

The windows machine has an older processor, Geode Integrated Processor.

Found the answer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx

1. Open the Property Pages dialog box for the project.
2. Select the C/C++ folder.
3. Select the Code Generation property page.
4. Modify the Enable Enhanced Instruction Set property.

In my case I needed to change this to /arch:IA32. Bam! Works! Thank you all for the brainstorming session.